# Displaying a form once for login and validate at the same time

Tags: c#, forms, validation

I am creating a booking system where users can register and log in.
What the code do is that it has a list of Useraccounts objects which collect each users' created account. Hence for both register and login, i will have a form for each respectively. The booking form will be displayed when their credentials are validated.

**The problem i am facing is when any user log in how am i going to display the booking form once and at the same time validating when click on the login button on the login form?**

My code for the register form is shown below.

```
public partial class Register : Form

{

    Login_page login;

    public Register(Login_page l)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        login = l;
    }


    public static List<UserAccount> UserAccounts = new List<UserAccount>();

    Login_page lp = new Login_page(UserAccounts);

    int count = UserAccounts.Count;

    public List<UserAccount> AddUserAccounts()
    {

        UserAccounts.Add(new UserAccount
        {
            Name = NameReg.Text,
            Username = UsernameReg.Text,
            Password = PasswordReg.Text,
            Email = EmailReg.Text,
            Address = AddressReg.Text,
            CardNum = int.Parse(CardNumReg.Text),
            PaymentType = PaymentTypeReg.Text

        });

        MessageBox.Show("Register was successful!");

        count++;
        return UserAccounts;
    }

    private void CANAReg_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddUserAccounts();
    }

    private void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        login.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }
}
```

And the code for the login form (which i am having problem at here) is shown below.

```
 public partial class Login_page : Form
{
    Register r;
    //public List<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    public static List<UserAccount> UserAccounts = new List<UserAccount>();

    public Login_page(List<UserAccount> UV1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserAccounts = UV1;
    }

    public Login_page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        r = new Register(this);
    }



    private void Calculations()
    {

      for (int i = 0; i< UserAccounts.Count ; i++)
        {

            if (UsernameLogin.Text.Equals(UserAccounts[i].Username) && PasswordLogin.Text.Equals(UserAccounts[i].Password))
            {

                Booking bookings = new Booking();
                bookings.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Please check your username or password");
            UsernameLogin.Focus();
        }

       }


    private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculations();
    }

    private void CANA_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Register reg = new Register(this);
        reg.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

**I am having a problem at the calculations part. Which what i want is that when any user clicks on the login button yet validating at the same time, booking form will not be displayed multiple times.**

Comment: I am unsure why you are using a loop, but I presume you have a good reason for it.  The solution I provided is to `break` out of the loop once conditions have been met for the first time.

Comment: Because I want to loop through the list and validate the users' credentials. Apparently I think is hard because which user account created first matters. For example even though the second user has the correct credentials, they will not be able to log in as their user account is created in the second place of the list. May i know is this limitation limited to only 1 user account? if not do you have any solutions to offer? because I really cant think of it because i just learnt c#.. Thanks in advance and Happy New Year! @KraangPrime

Comment: Btw, the break helps to stop. But It doesnt solve my problem, although i know what i want but i dont know how to implement it. I tried different approaches but is still not working.. @KraangPrime

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are missing is the `break;` command to exit the loop early once your conditions have been satisfied.

Try replacing the `Caculations` method with this code :

```
private void Calculations()
{

    for (int i = 0; i< UserAccounts.Count ; i++)
    {

        if (UsernameLogin.Text.Equals(UserAccounts[i].Username) && PasswordLogin.Text.Equals(UserAccounts[i].Password))
        {

            Booking bookings = new Booking();
            bookings.Show();
            this.Hide();
            break;
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check your username or password");
            UsernameLogin.Focus();
        }

    }

}
```